# PHP protect a folder

Tags: php

I need to secure a folder. Website was done in PHP. There is an admin area with files like PDF, DOC… so; I cannot protect these files with session variable. Is there a way in PHP to protect a folder?

Thank you

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, as such, you do know that you can move files outside of the web-root, and have them still-accessible by the server and scripts thereon? If you have an authorisation mechanism then they should be just as safe, if not safer, there than in a php-protected directory.

Comment: I'd agree with @ricebowl...if these files aren't meant to be served directly via the website, it makes sense to place them outside of the web-root and access them via script only.

Answer (score 4):

You can't protect it using only PHP, but with the help of a .htaccess file, this is possible.

Create a .htaccess file in the directory you want to protect, and put this in it:

```
Deny from all
```

Then, to create a PHP script to access the files, you can do something like this:

```
// Add user authentication code
$name = 'protected_dir/file.pdf';
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your files behind the viewable area(before public_html) and with a session protected download page, download the files.

```
<?php
if(session_is_loggedin()){
    readfile($_GET['file']);

}
?>
```

Obviously, there need to be some extra changes but that is the part you requested.