# Best strategy to protect downloadable files -php/mysql Apache2 server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'll trying to figure out how to protect directory from unauthorized or not autentificated user to download files.
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can't find a good duplicate, but a little search will bring up results like this [PHP protect a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120174/php-protect-a-folder)

There is a simple way to restrict folder access based on PHP session authorization using php. It requires creating stub files for valid authorized sesssions (and automating their deletion). In PHP you do:

```
if ($user_has_permission_to_download)
{
   touch("tmp/access-" . session_id()); 
}
```

Then a simple rewriterule+rewritecond can then serve for authorization:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        PHPSESSID=(\w+)
RewriteCond ../tmp/access-%1      -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  $1  [L]

RewriteRule .+  /deny   [L]
```

The first block permits access when the according cookie value is found and an authorization stub file exists. The second rule blocks access for anyone else.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great idea. I have adopted this and modified to fit my needs, but the core is still the same as in this great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Put a .htaccess file in the directory with the files, with the following content

```
deny from all
```

Then create a script that that uses for instance [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to serve the file if the user is authorized.

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess is your best friend. Put deny from all into that .htaccess file. Or if you don't want to use .htaccess file encrypt and change all the time the download path (LOL!).

Comment: You should expand on that answer. It isn't very helpful at the moment.

Comment: You are right - but I don't want to delete my answer. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a users / login script somewhere that authenticates a user?
Use .htaccess rewrite rules to forward the file request through a php script that checks a session variable if the user is logged in then returns the file.

Something of the elk:

```
.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(pdf|exe|doc|whatever)$ some-script.php?file=$1.$2 [L]

<?php
if(loginCheck()) //function somewhere that checks session if user is logged in
{
  return fopen('../files/' . $_GET['file']); //open and return the requested file
}
```

This is just pseudo code to give you an idea of what you need to do. You may also have to echo the correct file headers as well.

And to stop people from just going to the files directory, I recommend putting an .htaccess file in THAT folder as well saying `deny from all` to stop EVERYONE from accessing it.

Comment: Not important, but `elk` should be `ilk`. ;-)