# How to use Apache/PHP to protect directories from users that aren't logged in

Tags: php, apache

My friend and I are building website that allows users to upload images. We have got this all sorted but we were wondering how to stop members of the public being able to access the files on the server, but allowing members to access them. Is there an Apache mod that would let us do this and link it with a PHP script to check if users are logged in?

Comment: Either use a `readfile()`-wrapper script for download links, or setup tempfiles with session ids to probe via RewriteCond.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP protect a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120174/php-protect-a-folder)

Comment: you can also use .htaccess file to protect folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is an apache module you can use for authentication: [`mod_auth`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_auth.html).

It supports multiple backends, so you can make your application share the credentials with it.

Apache itself is extendible at authentication as well, there are other modules that support a mysql database which is called `mod_auth_mysql` of which multiple variants exist. A better choice might be [`mod_authn_dbd`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html) for Apache 2.2 as it offers a generic interface to SQL databases of multiple flavors. As well, ldap is supported: [`mod_authnz_ldap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html).

Another alternative is using you PHP for authentication and then commanding the server to provide the file. That's often referred as `X-Sendfile` or [`mod_xsendfile`](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/), which is a third-party module.

If you're looking for a PHP only solution, one question that talks about it is [**How to password protect files (images, video, zip) dynamically from public and allow access to members only?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2416736/367456).