# How to secure a folder with html, css, js and php files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security

I have exactly the same question as [is asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120174/php-protect-a-folder), but I want to place websites in that folder (with html, css, js, php etc.). So my question is how that is done exactly?

More specific:
In one page you log in, then I will redirect you to another php file which shows an iframe with websites that are placed in this folder.

Thanks already!

Comment: You need an authentication system: https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/php-authentication-system , http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php or https://daveismyname.blog/login-and-registration-system-with-php. Many other examples exist.

Comment: Yeah I have a login made already, but in this directory I will place folders with other websites where I can't check if they are logged in...

Comment: You can prevent accessing the specific files (with format) by `.htaccess`, then load them after auth in php code with buffer or other solutions.

Comment: Yahya could you be more specific (with code or so) please?